# Xamarin Android and Azure SQL

Tags: c#, android, sql-server, azure, xamarin.android

I'm a second-year student and, I have an `Azure SQL Database` which is maintained by me using the `SSMS`. I use this database to interact with my `ASP.NET` Application for CRUD Operations and is hosted in Azure Cloud. I made a `Xamarin Android` Application same as the `ASP.NET` Application and now I want to use that Application and Insert, Update, Select and Delete data from the `Azure SQL database`.

It would be so nice of you if someone can

1) Walk me through the best industrial standard of doing above task
2) Explain the difference between Azure SQL and Easy Tables

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

its not possible to connect Xamarin  android application from sql server directly. for this you have to connect through webapi /web services.  first develop webapi with sql db operations and call web api from your Xamarin application.

xamrin application --> web api --> sql server.

Comment: Hi, @sukumar2267, Thanks but the question is how :-)

Comment: first create web api in visual studio. deploy the web api in iis. now you have to use the hosted link in your xamarin application.https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/consuming/rest/

Comment: Hi, Thanks again, Does this link show the same thing as you mentioned? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-android-get-started thanks :-)

Comment: yes, you have to follow the same, if you have any question let me know.

Comment: Hi, Link you posted helped me a lot to learn about RESTful services and thanks a lot. So for my understanding that link is for the client devices and service side programming is done by [Following ASP.NET Core Web Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mobile/native-mobile-backend) 1) Am I right? 2) If Yes if I use usual SqlConnection ADO.NET classes to insert data received from above HttpPost Method?

Comment: yes , you have to ado.net in restful service for database operations.

Answer (score 2):

For performing crud operations from xamarin to sql azure. 
Azure Mobile app sdk is perfect for you. It is designed for this kind of purpose.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started

remember, you are going to need Mobile App (Azure App service) hosted in azure with some basic configurations. Above link should guide you

Comment: Hi, Just to clarify my understanding, so while I create the data connection if I make it with my excising Azure SQL database can I retrieve data from the tables I used in my ASP.NET Application? Thanks